# Extract first and last values among a number of columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have observed subjects `a`-`d` during 2-4 years and each year they reported a numerical value. I want to extract the first and last value of each subject, ignoring NAs. How do I create the new variables `first_value` and `last_value`? In this example, I have included the desired result:

```
df <- data.frame(subject = c("a","b","c","d"), 
                 year1 = c(1, 2, NA, NA),
                 year2 = c(3, 4, NA, 5),
                 year3 = c(6, 7, 8, NA),
                 year4 = c(9, 10, NA, 11),
                 first_value <- c(1, 2, 8, 5),
                 last_value <- c(9, 10, 8, 11))
```

And what would be the solution if variables `year1`-`year4` were categorical?

Comment: `?max.col` on `!is.na(df[c("year1", "year2", "year3", "year4")])` might be handy here  -- once with `ties.method = "first"` and once with "last" to return the column indices of the respective values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, `:=` (first_value = na.omit(unlist(.SD))[1], 
                  last_value = tail(na.omit(unlist(.SD)),1)), 
          by = subject][]
```

which gives:

```
   subject year1 year2 year3 year4 first_value last_value
1:       a     1     3     6     9           1          9
2:       b     2     4     7    10           2         10
3:       c    NA    NA     8    NA           8          8
4:       d    NA     5    NA    11           5         11
```

---

Following the suggestion of @alexis_laz, you can use `max.col` as follows to get the repective values:

```
f <- max.col(!is.na(df[c("year1", "year2", "year3", "year4")]), 'first')
l <- max.col(!is.na(df[c("year1", "year2", "year3", "year4")]), 'last')

df$first_value <- sapply(seq_along(f), function(i) df[,-1][i,f[i]])
df$last_value <- sapply(seq_along(l), function(i) df[,-1][i,l[i]])
```

which will get you the same result. As suggested by @alexis_laz in the comments, this can be further improved to:

```
m <- as.matrix(df[c("year1", "year2", "year3", "year4")])

f <- max.col(!is.na(m), 'first')
l <- max.col(!is.na(m), 'last')

df$first_value <- df[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df), f)]
df$last_value <- df[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df), l)]
```

---

And using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(year, val, 2:5) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  summarise(first_value = first(val),
            last_value = last(val)) %>% 
  left_join(df, ., by = 'subject')
```

WARNING: A variation of this without using `filter` and using `na.omit(val)` (or `val[!is.na(val)]`) in `summarise`:

```
df %>% 
  gather(year, val, 2:5) %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  summarise(first_value = first(na.omit(val)),
            last_value = last(na.omit(val))) %>% 
  left_join(df, ., by = 'subject')
```

won't work as a result of the bugs reported [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2090) and [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1980).

Comment: Just a small note -- `sapply(seq_along(f), function(i) df[, -1][i, f[i]])` could be replaced by `df[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df), f)]`. And, I guess, saving a `m = as.matrix(df[c("year1", "year2", "year3", "year4")])` and working on that should save some coercions

Answer (score 0):

using `data.frame` and `gather`

```
#Used packages
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

subject<-c("a","b","c","d")  
year1 <- c(1, 2, NA, NA)  
year2 <- c(3, 4, NA, 5)  
year3 <- c(6, 7, 8, NA)  
year4 <- c(9, 10, NA, 11)  

dt = data.frame(subject, year1, year2, year3, year4)
```

`gather()` to collapse the multiple columns into a single column

```
dt <- dt %>% gather(year, value, year1:year4)
```

`summarise( )`:  to perform summary statistics on the selected variables

```
dt %>% group_by(subject)%>% 
        summarise(first_value = min(value, na.rm=TRUE),
                  last_value = max(value, na.rm=TRUE))
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  subject first_value last_value
   <fctr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1       a           1          9
2       b           2         10
3       c           8          8
4       d           5         11
```

Comment: This suggestion creates "first_value" and "last_value" with only NAs

Comment: Look at the added output, I have got.

Comment: Although this gives the desired result for the example data, this won't be always the case. Your solution selects the minimum and maximum results not the first and the last.

Comment: Thanks @ProcrastinatusMaximus, Somehow overseen it. I will edit the solution after finding the relevant solution. I am still skeptical about what the user want !

Comment: @Prradep see my answer for a possible `dplyr`/`tidyr` solution ;-)

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Yes, I have noticed your latest edit for `dplyr/tidyr` solution inclusion ;-) Good one !

Comment: Thanks @Prradep, the solution från ProcrastinusMaximus worked!